# How do you change the font-size of a custom css style?

Tags: css, styles, font-size, head

How do you change the font-size of a custom css style using javascript?

I've seen examples of how to replace inline styles using javascript but I can't find how to replace an attribute like font-size in a non-inline custom style in a header. For example I'd like to use javascript to change the font-size from 12px 20px using javascript.

```
<head>
<style>
.mystyle{
font-size:12px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

**html**:

```
<p class="mystyle">This is some text.</p>
```

**javascript**:

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("mystyle")[0].style.fontSize="120%";
}
```

You can also set the fontsize as `smaller` , `larger`, in `length` units and also inherit font-size of parent element.

Comment: This may have the desired effect, but it does not do what the question asked for: it does not replace anything in the `style` element, it just introduces some rules that override its effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('CLASSNAME')
```

gives you an array with all the class elements, you could use a loop to change every nodes style, you can access them like a usual array with [].
I'm not sure if there's a more comfortable way

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to set the font-size of an object.

```
Object.style.fontSize="value|inherit"
```

So, for example, if you open console on this page and run:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.fontSize = '35px'
```

You will see the header of this page increase.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the style sheet specified in a `style` element, you can modify the element content:

```
s = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
s.innerHTML += '.mystyle { font-size: 20px; }';
```

This does not change the existing rule but appends one that overrides it.

Alternatively, you can use the `sheet` property of the `style` element as defined in [CSSOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/):

```
var sh = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].sheet;
sh.insertRule('.mystyle { font-size: 20px; }', sh.cssRules.length);
```

If you really wanted to *replace* a rule in the `style` element and not just override it, you would need to locate it, traversing the `cssRules` object and getting an index, then calling `deleteRule` and then `insertRule`.