# In addEventListener : can't access propery "font" because element.style is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have an HTML file where I include a JS script. In my HTML file I have multiples elements that need to have behave same. This a part of my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body class="bodyForm">
    <center>
        <div class="boxForm">
            <p class="titlebox" id="p1">Question 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="boxForm">
            <p class="titlebox" id="p2">Question 2</p>
        </div>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="formulaireScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS :

```js
let quest1Title = document.getElementById("p1");
let quest2Title = document.getElementById("p2");
function increaseFontSize(element) { 
    element.style.font = "2.5em"; 
    console.log("hi")
}
quest1Title.addEventListener('onmouseover', increaseFontSize(this));
quest2Title.addEventListener('onmouseover', increaseFontSize(this));
```

However, when my page loads, a `TypeError` is thrown in console, saying that it can't access property "font" because element.style is undefined.

So my guess would be that when this script loads, JS tries to run the function once to test for errors or other things but since there is no element at all, an error happens before addEventListener statement is executed. But I am absolutely not sure

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes it is. The font parameter is defined in my CSS. Is that a problem ? Can't JS override the CSS value ?

Comment: @Yousaf well I think `this` would be the HTMLelement which I am assigning the eventListener to

Comment: Naaa.... I replied too fast forget it ;)

Comment: If you change `increaseFontSize(this)` to `increaseFontSize`, then `this` inside the event handler will be the html element on which you added the `mouseover` event.

Comment: Can you refer this answer for more https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957103/13833218 ?

Comment: Just to be more clear, do you want to change only the font size of the paragraph

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change the font-size of a custom css style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583016/how-do-you-change-the-font-size-of-a-custom-css-style)

Comment: @Masood well no since I want to change font-size only when mouse if over the paragraph

Comment: @ScarySneer It is the same concept, you just put it inside the mouseover event callback function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your addEventListener registration, there are two errors:

1. The event isnt `onmouseover`, but `mouseover`
2. the `(this)` is calling the `increaseFontSize` immediately instead of passing the function reference.

Then in your function, the argument is not the element, but the event object. So that is why `element.style` is not defined. `element` is not the element, as you thought. Use `this` instead ;)

Here is your script fixed. I added the `mouseleave` event binded to a `restoreFontSize` function.

```js
let quest1Title = document.getElementById("p1");
let quest2Title = document.getElementById("p2");

let consoleLogged = false // Just to ease that demo

function increaseFontSize(event) {

  if(!consoleLogged){
    console.log(event)
    console.log(this)
    consoleLogged = true
  }
  
  // Set a fontSize
  this.style.fontSize = "2.5em"; 
}
function restoreFontSize(event) {

  // Restore (or clear) the inline fontSize property
  this.style.fontSize = ""; 
}

quest1Title.addEventListener('mouseover', increaseFontSize);
quest2Title.addEventListener('mouseover', increaseFontSize);

quest1Title.addEventListener('mouseleave', restoreFontSize);
quest2Title.addEventListener('mouseleave', restoreFontSize);
```

```html
<body class="bodyForm">
  <center>
    <div class="boxForm">
      <p class="titlebox" id="p1">Question 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="boxForm">
      <p class="titlebox" id="p2">Question 2</p>
    </div>
  </center>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="formulaireScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your anwser. I have a question about the script you wrote. Why do you define increaseFontSize with an event argument when you do not pass any argument to the function in the EventListener statement ? Also, what is this way of "calling" a function without parentheses ? What does it do ?

Comment: When you register an eventListener, you have to "pass" the function reference so that when the event fires, it gets executed. So the "executer" is the event engine, which is passing it the triggering event object as argument for you to use (or not).

Comment: If the function is executed immediately, what is passed to the event engine is the result of the function (so `undefined` since the function returns nothing) instead of the function reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function increaseFontSize(event) { 
    event.target.style.font = "2.5em"; 
    console.log("hi")
}
 
... 

quest1Title.addEventListener('mouseover', increaseFontSize); 

//shorthand for

quest1Title.addEventListener('mouseover', event => increaseFontSize(event));
```

`increaseFontSize(this)` immediately calls the function, your current implemention is the equivalent of

```
quest1Title.addEventListener('onmouseover', undefined);
```

`undefined` being `increaseFontSize(this)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let quest1Title = document.getElementById("p1");
let quest2Title = document.getElementById("p2");
function increaseFontSize(ev) { 
    ev.target.style.fontSize = "2.5em"; 
    console.log("hi")
}
quest1Title.addEventListener('mouseover', increaseFontSize);
quest2Title.addEventListener('mouseover', increaseFontSize);
```

```html
<center>
        <div class="boxForm">
            <p class="titlebox" id="p1">Question 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="boxForm">
            <p class="titlebox" id="p2">Question 2</p>
        </div>
    </center>
```

There are a few reasons why your code didn't work.

What you know as `onmouseover` is a function, the events themselves are without the "on". mouseover, click, and so on.

When you assign a function callback to a listener, you don't need to assign `this`, its already added, so just write the function name without parenthesis, `increaseFontSize`.

As for the style, use `fontSize`.

Lastly, what invoked the listener? The event, so the event is actually the value that passes to the function. From there you can get the element through the `target` attribute.

And because I like using CSS when possible, here's the same result without JS.

```css
p.titlebox:hover {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="boxForm">
    <p class="titlebox" id="p1">Question 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxForm">
    <p class="titlebox" id="p2">Question 2</p>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Oh well thank you. I am not using CSS because, when I add some more code to this script, it will trigger some other things so I am forced to use JS

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help

```js
const titleBox = document.querySelectorAll(".titlebox");
titleBox.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
    event.target.style.fontSize = "2.5em";
  })
});

titleBox.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
    event.target.style.fontSize = "unset";
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body class="bodyForm">
    <div>
        <div class="boxForm">
            <p class="titlebox" id="p1">Question 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="boxForm">
            <p class="titlebox" id="p2">Question 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="formulaireScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```